# Restrict user to go back using browser back button or at least restrict in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

In my SPA,
**I want to restrict the user from going back from browser buttons,**

When the user logs in to my application the page refreshes and lands on homePage, but if the user presses back (page refreshes here) he/she should be logged off from the application (if not logged off at least restrict user).

I have tried to put a dialog box while the component unmounts, but it is not called because the page is refreshing always.

I have also tried to disable the back button on my homePage, but this approach ain't working.

Comment: Redesign the app such that it updates the page content dynamically rather than relying on page loading. (It's a single page app, after all, so shouldn't need to cause reloads.) Now that the page doesn't get reloaded, the session can be stored as a javascript object which would be lost if the user navigates away.

Comment: @Ouroborus For login, it goes to a 3rd party application, and that is why the the reload takes place

Comment: If there's no way to cause that login process to be entirely embedded in your page, your app isn't really single-page. Regardless, you might look at the [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) or [`unload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload) events.